# Dropdown placeholder working in FF not in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, html.dropdownlistfor

I create dropdown in mvc

```
@Html.dropdownlistFor(model=>model.modelname,new{placeholder="Please Select One"})
```

The placeholder working fine in **FireFox.But didnt working in Chrome**.

How to Solve this?

Comment: How exactly didn't it work? Any errors in the Chrome console?

Comment: I didnt get any errors

Answer (score 1):

Remove `placeholder` and use drop down like this,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelname, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.modelname, "Please Select One", new { @class = "select" })
```